# mysql_result repaced with mysqli_data_seek not counting correctly

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to upgrade to Mysqli from Mysql and by that function `mysql_result` to `mysqli_data_seek`. I managed to do this, but all the statistics are wrong, I get counted only 1 instead of 520.

I believe that the problem stays in `mysqli_data_seek($res, 0);` because `mysql_result` was like this `mysql_result($res, 0, 0);` (it had 3 arguments).

New Code  (Mysqi):

```
$link  = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$query = "SELECT name FROM employee";
$res   = mysqli_query($link, $query)

if (mysqli_num_rows($res) == 0) {
    return false;
}

if (mysqli_num_fields($res) > 1) {
    return $this->sqlFetchArray($res);
} else {
    return mysqli_data_seek($res, 0);
}
```

Old Code (Mysql):

```
$link  = mysql_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password");
$query = "SELECT name FROM employee";
$res   = mysql_query($query);

if (mysql_num_rows($res) == 0) {
    return false;
}

if (mysql_num_fields($res) > 1) {
    return $this->sqlFetchArray($res);
} else {
    return mysql_result($res, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: `mysqli_data_seek()` sets a pointer, and returns a boolean true/false; it doesn't return a result

Comment: @MarkBaker So what can I use to return the same behaviour of mysql_result.

Comment: @user3650099: Question is, why did you use that function in the first place? Unless we don't know why you did the mistake how should we be able to give good guidance?

Comment: DO NOT use mysql_result. DO NOT use mysqli_data_seek

Comment: He ie using this function because it was shown in some ancient tutorial from the last century. Since then he is just copy-pasteing it from one project to another, like any other lawful PHP user. Programming *is* a copy-pasteing in PHP world. And this thing of mysql ext deprecation is a true disaster, as it doesn't allow just copy and paste some code!

Comment: This is my entire file upgraded from mysql to mysqli. http://pastebin.com/ZD24n6Wb. I know that I tried using mysqli_result and it send me call to undefined function mysqli_result, that is because is not existent.

Comment: Do a mysqli_fetch_array() or mysqli_fetch_object(), and extract the column that you want to return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysqli_data_seek` is a member of `mysqli_result` that moves the pointer to an arbitrary row passed into the function.

From [the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php):

```
$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER BY Name";
if ($result = $mysqli->query( $query)) {

    /* seek to row no. 400 */
    $result->data_seek(399);

    /* fetch row */
    $row = $result->fetch_row();

    printf ("City: %s  Countrycode: %s\n", $row[0], $row[1]);

    /* free result set*/
    $result->close();
}
```

The problem you are having is to do with changing from `mysql` to `mysqli` and is [described here by tuxedobob](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php#109782):

> Converting an old project from using the mysql extension to the mysqli
>   extension, I found the most annoying change to be the lack of a
>   corresponding mysql_result function in mysqli. While mysql_result is a
>   generally terrible function, it was useful for fetching a single
>   result field *value* from a result set (for example, if looking up a
>   user's ID).
>
> The behavior of mysql_result is approximated here, though you may want
>   to name it something other than mysqli_result so as to avoid thinking
>   it's an actual, built-in function.

```
<?php 
function mysqli_result($res, $row, $field=0) { 
    $res->data_seek($row); 
    $datarow = $res->fetch_array(); 
    return $datarow[$field]; 
} 
?>
```

> Implementing it via the OO interface is left as an exercise to the
>   reader.

Comment: This is what I needed will mark as accepted as soon as 4 min passed. Don't get the downvote of the answer though.

Comment: @YourCommonSense He had given me great answer, brilliant answer I might say, I though SO is a QA Site.

Comment: Surely it's brilliant. Save for the fact you don't need (and shouldn't use at all) either mysql_result, data_seek, and that terrible error- and injection-prone class from pastebin.

Comment: @YourCommonSense You're wasting your breath. IF you want to suggest an alternate answer, then do so, I'm sure you'll get the appropriate upvotes for your context, sanity and mind. If you're not going to do that, why are you even bothering to comment? I'm yet to identify anyone who cares what you have to say, but perhaps I have not spent long enough in my SO "career". Either way, your implicit protest that I was able to answer the user's question more swiftly and succinctly than you has no real merit. Ciao.

Comment: Really, you'll make even better career than I thought at first.

Answer (score -1):

I think what Your Common Sense is trying to say in his comments is that it doesn't make sense to retrieve a bunch of data from your database and then sift through it in your PHP. The database is *for* finding exactly the data you need, so you should use it for that.

You should be using some combination of WHERE, ORDER BY, and LIMIT clauses in your SQL.

Perhaps you want to find the recently hired employee whose salary is just below 500.

```
SELECT `name` FROM `employee` WHERE `hire_date` > '2014-05-01' AND `salary` < 500 ORDER BY `salary` DESC LIMIT 1
```

You are trying to use PHP where you should be using SQL. You won't need data seek if you write your SQL to get just the information you need, which is what SQL is for.

Comment: nope. what I wanted to say is that the OP don't need (and shouldn't use at all) either mysql_result, data_seek, and that terrible error- and injection-prone class they pasted in pastebin.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Isn't that what I just said? Thanks for the downvote.